# What does !something mean in my terminal/shell before the directory? (Using MacOS)

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, theme

[image: terminal ss]

What does the !w mean which is present before the directory path?
Are there other such symbol

here is my output to $PS1 - https://pastebin.mozilla.org/5GuTTbqU:

```
${$((_p9k_on_expand()))+}%{${_p9k__raw_msg-}${_p9k__raw_msg::=}%}${(e)_p9k_t[7]}${_p9k__1-${${:-${_p9k__d::=0}${_p9k__rprompt::=${_p9k__1r-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=8}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1r:+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%k%f${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%f}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%f}${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}${${:-"${${(%):-%j}:#0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=""}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=12}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+14}}${_p9k__n:=15}${_p9k__v:}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rbackground_jobs+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__v}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{070\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{070\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{070\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${${(M)${#P9K_GCLOUD_PROJECT_NAME}:#0}:+$P9K_GCLOUD_ACCOUNT$P9K_GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::="${P9K_GCLOUD_ACCOUNT//\%/%%}:${P9K_GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID//\%/%%}"}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=16}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+18}}${_p9k__n:=19}${P9K_VISUAL_IDENTIFIER::=gcloud}${_p9k__v::=gcloud}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID//\%/%%}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rgcloud+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__v}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{032\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{032\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{032\}}${_p9k__i::=28}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"$P9K_GCLOUD_PROJECT_NAME"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::="${P9K_GCLOUD_ACCOUNT//\%/%%}:${P9K_GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID//\%/%%}"}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=20}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+22}}${_p9k__n:=23}${P9K_VISUAL_IDENTIFIER::=gcloud}${_p9k__v::=gcloud}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_GCLOUD_PROJEC}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rgcloud+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__v}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{032\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{032\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{032\}}${_p9k__i::=28}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${${(%):-%#}:#\#}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=%n@%m}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=24}}${_p9k__n}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rcontext+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{180\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{180\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{180\}}${_p9k__i::=31}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${${(%):-%#}:#\%}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=%B%n@%m}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=28}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rcontext+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{178\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{178\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{178\}}${_p9k__i::=31}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}$_p9k__sss%b%k%f}}${_p9k__lprompt::=${_p9k__1l-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=%f}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::="%{d%}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}${(Q)${:-"usr"}}${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+local}:-${:-"%F{103}"}lo${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=3))+}}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}bin${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}%{d%}"}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=136}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+138}}${_p9k__n:=139}${_p9k__}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1ldir+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__v}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{031\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\}}${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}${(e)_p9k__vcs}${${:-"${${:-$_p9k__keymap.$_p9k__zle_state}:#(vicmd.*|vivis.*|vivli.*|*.*overwrite*)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=?}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=36}}${_p9k__n:=${${(}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1lprompt_char+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{076\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${${:-$_p9k__keymap.$_p9k__zle_state}:#(vicmd.*|vivis.*|vivli.*|*.*insert*)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=?}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=40}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+42}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1lprompt_char+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{076\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#vicmd0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=?}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=44}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+46}}${_p9k__n:=47}${_p9k__}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1lprompt_char+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{076\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#(vicmd1|vivis?|vivli?)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=?}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=48}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+50}}${_p9k}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1lprompt_char+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{076\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}%b%k$_p9k__sss%b%k%f${:-" %b%k%f"}}}}+}${(e)_p9k_t[6]}${${_p9k__h::=50.}+}${${_p9k__d::=$((_p9k__m-_p9k__h))}+}${_p9k__lprompt/\%\{d\%\}*\%\{d\%\}/${_p9k__1ldir-/${:-"%B%F{039}"}${(Q)${:-"usr"}}${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+local}:-${:-"%F{103}"}lo${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=3))+}}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}bin${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}}}${${_p9k__m::=$((_p9k__d+_p9k__h))}+}}${${COLUMNS::=$_p9k__clm}+}
```

EDIT1 - I am using powerlevel10k theme for iterm2 if that helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152530/what-does-w-mean-in-my-terminal-using-macos?noredirect=1#comment132619251_75152530 I came here asking this after posting at wrong place

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really not sensible to expect us to debug an unreadable PS1 variable that contains suspicious variable names like `GLOUD_ACCOUNT`, especially as you do not explain how you came up with that prompt

Comment: I'd say your prompt string looks like it has been generated by some program, and is way too complex to be reasonably decoded by hand. A more reasonable way to analyze it would be to see the "source code" that builds the prompt, or in other words, any prompt-related settings in your `~/.p10k.zsh` file.

Comment: thanks @telcoM , Should I share my .p10k.zsh file if that helps? I am not really sure what to look for in the file

Comment: The `!w` represent the LOCK_ICON (that's defined in [internals/icons.zsh](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/internal/icons.zsh)). There are several declarations of `LOCK_ICON` and one of those is `!w`, There is one which works for me: `\UE0A2`. If I do: `echo  '\UE0A2'` I get the lock character. BTW I only checked the source code of the repository and I didn't test the theme because it's very suspicious this repo includes variables such as `CLOUD_ACCOUNT` as well as your `PS1` output is very large and prints a short prompt.

Comment: thanks @Edgar so what does lock actually mean in terms of Unix Shells?

Comment: Sharing your .p10k.zsh file would be a much better idea than asking people to decode the massive prompt string it can produce. I don't know much about powerlevel10k, but after a quick browse through the configuration examples, it looks like the `!w` (`LOCK_ICON`) might simply mean that **your current working directory is not writeable** for your current user account. Would this make sense in your situation?

Comment: yes it does! my query is resolved with the link @Edgar shared (as for the $PS1 output , I shared because when I asked the question on stackoverflow ,someone mentioned to do so, I am new to Mac environment and was not familiar with .p10k.zsh file)

Comment: Although the `GCLOUD` variables buried amidst a bunch of spaghetti looks suspicious, I believe it is explained here: https://github.com/championswimmer/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/.p10k.zsh#L1322